# Sending POST http request in java

Tags: java, curl

What is the best way to translate the next curl request to a single Java request code?

```
$ curl -i
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -F "user[photo]=@test.jpg" \
  -F "user[first_name]=Test" \
  -F "user[password]=password" \
  -F "user[email]=email@test.com" \
  -F "user[last_name]=Testing" \
  -X POST http://someURL.com:3000/api/user?client_id=zyBCF8N6yiJq8k
```

*I've already tried the next:

```
    HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(AP("users", null));
    FileBody bin = new FileBody(new File(IMAGE_DIR + "/" + "nisbet-profile.jpg"));
    log.info("exporting file in path " + bin.getFile().getPath());
    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
    entity.addPart("photo", bin);
    entity.addPart("first_name", new StringBody("test"));
    entity.addPart("last_name", new StringBody("test"));
    entity.addPart("email", new StringBody("testemail23@gmail.com"));
    entity.addPart("password", new StringBody("123456"));

    RestExporter picExporter = new RestExporter();
    postRequest.setEntity(entity);
    HttpResponse response = picExporter.request(postRequest);



    but I get: HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity

    Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
```

Comment: dupe https://docs.google.com/a/boomi.com/document/d/1xADNwd9Fj4sPch9czPOOcAYIXEwiS446hw7o0A2aC_o/edit#heading=h.4zos6y9oy1hf

Answer (score 2):

### Look up what the `curl` options mean

```
-i, --include (HTTP)
-H, --header <header>
-F, --form <name=content>
-X, --request <command>
```

### Think about what these options mean

- You include HTTP headers
- You set `Content-Type` and `Accept` headers
- You set form fields
- You `POST` to a URL

### Use Apache HttpComponents

- Go to https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/ and read the documentation.
- Write your code.